# Ubuntu Cloud Guest no password

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Ubuntu's virtual machine on my computer (Windows 10, Hyper-V).
But I don't know my password, I think it seems to need to use cloud-config, how to configure this. Is it copied to the downloaded virtual machine? Still how?

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

1) You are not using a cloud, but instead using a hypervisor. This is fairly easy to work around - the Ubuntu Cloud Image developers made a path for this usage many years ago. See the [Ubuntu Wiki for the step-by-step procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#Ubuntu_Cloud_Guest_images_on_12.04_LTS_.28Precise.29_and_beyond_using_NoCloud). You must create a seed file to add your own password, then add your seed file to the cloud-image.

2) Unfortunately, the cloud-tools you need to edit the cloud-image are written for Linux, and don't work on Windows.

If you are already comfortable with Linux, you can use an Ubuntu LiveUSB environment to generate the seed-file and edit the cloud-image.

If this is your first time using Linux, then I would recommend using the normal Server Image instead of a Cloud Image.